# std::initializer_list ambiguity in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, initializer-list

I'm trying to accept a std::initializer_list into a generic constructor like so:

```
template<typename T>
class Test{
  std::vector<T> V;

  Test(std::initializer_list<T>& list) : V(list){}

};
```

using

```
Test<int> test{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

But I get the error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'Test<int>' No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: VS appears to have been matured, nice. It doesn't anymore seem to allow binding '&' to temporaries.

Comment: Snarky, but I'll take it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Test(std::initializer_list<T>& list) : V(list){}
```

This takes the `std::initializer_list` by non-const reference, but you then try to bind a temporary to it, which is illegal

`std::initializer_list` is designed to be lightweight, so you can just pass it by value:

```
Test(std::initializer_list<T> list) : V(list){}
//                           ^ no &
```